# Path to maven folder within STS Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

I have downloaded STS 3.7.2 and would like to add the maven folder to the windows 8 classpaths. This way I would be able to use command line commands such as `mvn spring-boot:run`

But where do I find that one maven folder within the STS folder?

Comment: are you trying to add to "path"?  Or do you really mean "classpath"?

Comment: whatever it takes. I would like to use maven on command line but without downloading explicitly maven. I would rather use the version of maven, that came with STS along.

Comment: Iirc sts is bundling maven embedded which is not for use with command line. What makes it a concern for you to download maven?

Comment: hmm I didn't want to change anything with STS. But I just downloaded maven, added PATH to environment, added path in STS and it seems to work. Typing mvn - version in console

Comment: Actually downloading maven has nothing to do with sts. You can keep sts to use the default embedded maven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run the mvn command from the command line it runs

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe" -classpath "C:\opensource\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\..\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\opensource\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\..\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.home=C:\opensource\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\.." "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\opensource\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin" org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar is found in the following STS directory

```
./sts-3.6.4.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.6.2.20150902-0001/jars/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar
```

Having said that I think it would be far easier to just download the full maven from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi unzip it into any directory, then add the environment variable M2_HOME as ..../apache-maven-3.3.9 then add %M2_HOME%/bin to the path.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx. I downloaded the full version of maven and added everything to PATH and Spring Tool Suite.

Answer (score 0):

remember, in "STS", maven is not configured to work out of STS (and terminal usage is out of STS usage).
we have to install maven.
**follow the following to setup maven to work from terminal.**

maven download link is here

1. [download latest maven from here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)

   extract it where ever you want.
   i extracted as below (see the bin,boot,conf,... folders are shown below as in the image):
2. [image]

**as this maven download is extracted from zip file (it is not setup), you will have to add this extracted path to "PATH" variable in windows environment.
follow this to set environment path:**
3. [image]

4. [image]

5. [image]

6. [image]

now "mvn" command must work.

7. **in my case, i use STS**
**and i had to restart STS (spring tool suit) for "mvn" to work in terminal in sts**